# How to localize RPSystemBroadcastPickerView.title?

Tags: ios, swift, callkit

I am struggling with localizing RPSystemBroadcastPickerView.title.

#### In detail

- I found this is directly affected by value of CFBundleDisplayName in BroadcastExtension's info.plist.
  [image: Second Pic]
- So It should be localized with `InfoPlist.strings`.
- In the info.plist file, I set STRINGS_FILE_INFOPLIST_RENAME to `true`.
- and create InfoPlist.strings, and wrote it as follows:

```
// en.lproj (default)

"CFBundleDisplayName": "what i want english"
```

```
// ko.lproj

"CFBundleDisplayName": "what i want korean"
...
```

[image: english example]

- But it works like below. Are there any misses that I have set?

[image: Example]